# Is the MVVM of LayoutAwarePage enough?

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-8

Currently I am using MVVM Light but I see that LayoutAwarePage in Windows Store Apps offers its own basic MVVM implementation. What kind of MVVM implementation is recommended for Windows Store App? It seems that using MVVM Light, I could add redundant code. Maybe it is possible to integrate both systems?

Answer (score 2):

You might also be interested in checking out the Okra App Framework (http://okra.codeplex.com). It is an MVVM framework that is designed from the ground up for Windows 8 development and allows you to still use LayoutAwarePage for the visual states.

Andy

Answer (score 1):

I recently used the LayoutAwarePage in all pages of a project I did recently. I found it to be useful in terms of the its support of device orientation changes,navigation and process lifetime management ie:the windows appstore specific stuff when compare to the blank page.  LayoutAwarePages DefaultViewModel is great for a quick and easy way to get up and running but if you are wanting a pure implementation of the MVVM pattern in terms of testablity, loose coupling of components/seperation of concerns and minimal use of the code-behind you are probably on the right lines with MVVM light.

Anyway hope this was helpful and best of luck with you project.

Andrew